# chart xAxis extremes change/fix

Tags: highcharts

In my chart I want the change xAxis extremes depend on various series. 
Let say for series 1, If I hide/show series, the extremes of xAxis should not change. It should have same behavior like if I have ignoreHiddenSeries=false

But for series 2 the extremes should change on show/hide series, like if I have ignoreHiddenSeries=true

How can I achieve this?

I made a jsfiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/cjchLqaa/2/
In beginning xAxis has extremes 0,4 where series 1 and 2 are visible.
But if I hide series 1 then xAsis still should have same extremes as before.
But for series 2 it should change in its normal way.

jsfiddle code:

```
$(function () {
   $('#container').highcharts({
    chart:{
        //ignoreHiddenSeries:true,
    },

    xAxis: {

    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [0, 29.9],
            [1, 71.5],
            [2, 106.4]
        ]
    },
            {
        data: [
            [2, 29.9],
            [3, 71.5],
            [4, 106.4]
        ]
    }]
});


var chart=$('#container').highcharts();

 $("#button1").click(function () {
    var series = chart.series[0];

    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();

    } else {
        series.show();
    }
});

$("#button2").click(function () {
    var series = chart.series[1];

    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();

    } else {
        series.show();
    }
 });


});
```

Answer (score 5):

I would approach this by checking for the series name (or id), and if it meets the criteria, grab the x axis extremes, hide the series, and the use the original extremes values to run `setExtremes()`.

Like this:

```
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ext = this.xAxis.getExtremes();
    this.setVisible();
    if(this.name == 'Series 1') {
        this.xAxis.setExtremes(ext.min,ext.max);    
    }
    else {
        this.xAxis.setExtremes();
    }
}
```

Example, using the legendItemClick event:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/sas2jawm/

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#button1").click(function () {

    chart.options.chart.ignoreHiddenSeries = false;
    var series = chart.series[0];

    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();

    } else {
        series.show();
    }
});

$("#button2").click(function () {

    chart.options.chart.ignoreHiddenSeries = true;
    var series = chart.series[1];

    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();

    } else {
        series.show();
    }
 });
```